# Postgres performance tuning

Tags: postgresql

Does applying cluster on a Postgres table of size billion rows improve performance?

I am attempting to find out whether applying the cluster operation will improve the query times for a table that is very large.

Comment: Why don't you run some tests and benchmark the results?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html

> In cases where you are accessing single rows randomly within a table,
>   the actual order of the data in the table is unimportant. However, if
>   you tend to access some data more than others, and there is an index
>   that groups them together, you will benefit from using CLUSTER. If you
>   are requesting a range of indexed values from a table, or a single
>   indexed value that has multiple rows that match, CLUSTER will help
>   because once the index identifies the table page for the first row
>   that matches, all other rows that match are probably already on the
>   same table page, and so you save disk accesses and speed up the query.

as you can see cluster will improve or not peformance, depending on how you query the table, not on its size. Billion or million - it will benefit if you use the index on which you cluster the table and you tend to use some part of data more often, then other. And you don't very intensively change the data:

> When a table is clustered, it is physically reordered based on the
>   index information. Clustering is a one-time operation: when the table
>   is subsequently updated, the changes are not clustered. That is, no
>   attempt is made to store new or updated rows according to their index
>   order. (If one wishes, one can periodically recluster by issuing the
>   command again.

Comment: I assume if the billion row table was structured as follows 
tenant_pk, customer_pk, order_date, invoice_number

and I want to join with a table structured as follows
tenant_pk, customer_pk, address1, address2

Comment: Ignore above, this is what I wanted mention ~ So if the indexed column was used in a join the performance will not be more significant than regular index.  As the access to the indexed column would still be random vs being a range.

Comment: if you join on full match without additional `AND some recent`, I would expect no performance boost